# How to play videostreaming from internet android?

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have this streaming

```
http://www.tvrey.com/canal_5.html
```

I have tried with two ways

but always I got

Can't play this video.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

and this is the other way copied from this link

```
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888
```

but I get same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener l) to check if there is any error occurs during preparation or playback.

Comment: @angel please share your error code after implement the OnErrorListener so it is easier to troubleshoot.